# segmentation fault in slider puzzle

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault

I was trying to do the slider puzzle but after compilation there is a warning:

> puzzle.c: In function ‘main’: puzzle.c:50:6: warning: passing argument
>   1 of ‘choice’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by
>   default] puzzle.c:2:5: note: expected ‘int (*)[4]’ but argument is of
>   type ‘int’

When I run the program, when the program enters the function it gives SEGMENTATION FAULT

My program is below

```
int choice(int b[4][4],int *x,int y,int z,int c);    

int main()    
{        
  int i,j,row,col,p,s,c;        
  p=33;        
  int  w[4][4]={{ 2, 3, 4, 5},\
                { 7, 9,11,12},\
                {13,15,19,22},\
                {34,45,65,-1}};

  int  a[4][4]={{15,12, 3, 2},\
                { 4, 7,13,65},\
                {34, 9,45,22},\
                {5,11,19,-1}};

  printf("Welcome to the puzzle the puzzle matrix is below... enjoy!\n");


  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
      printf("\n");
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
      {
        printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
      }
    }

 printf("-1 is the empty block\n");
 printf("To exit Enter 0 and to continue Enter 1\n");
 printf("Do you want to start or exit\n");

 scanf("%d",&s);

 while(s==1)
   {
   choicer:
     {
     printf("Enter the block you want to move\n"); 
     printf("Enter the row number\n");
     scanf("%d",&row);

     printf("Enter the column number\n");
     scanf("%d",&col);    
     }

     if(row>3||col>3)
       {
         printf("Invalid row or col numbers\n");
         goto choicer;
       }

     choicel:
     {
       printf("The choices to move the block are :\n 2= right,\n 3=left,\n 4=up,\n 5=down\n");
       printf("Enter the choice\n");

       scanf("%d",&c);    
     }

     if(c!=2 && c!=3 && c!=4 && c!=5)
     {
       printf("Invalid choice");

       goto choicel;
     }

     choice(a[4][4],&p,row,col,c);

     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
       printf("\n");
       for(j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
         printf("%d",a[i][j]);
       }
     }

     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
         if(a[i][j]==w[i][j])
           {
         printf("Game finished.. YOU WON!!!");
           }
       }
     }

     printf("Do you want to exit? \n 0=exit ,\n 1=continue\n");

     scanf("%d",&s);
   }

}


int choice(int b[4][4],int *x,int y,int z,int c)

{

  int temp;

  if(c==4)

    {

      if(*x!=(((y-1)*10)+z))

    {

      printf("Invalid move");

      return b[4][4];

    }
      else

    {

      temp = b[y][z];

      b[y][z]=b[y-1][z];

      b[y-1][z]=temp;

      *x=(((y-1)*10)+z);

      return b[4][4];

     }

    }

  else if(c==5)

    {

      if(*x!=(((y+1)*10)+z))

    {

      printf("Invalid move");

      return b[4][4];

    }

      else

    {

      temp = b[y][z];

      b[y][z]=b[y+1][z];

      b[y+1][z]=temp;

      *x=(((y+1)*10)+z);

      return b[4][4];

     }

    }
  else if(c==2)

    {

      if(*x!=((y*10)+(z-1)))

    {

      printf("Invalid Move");

      return b[4][4];

    }

      else

    {

      temp=b[y][z];

      b[y][z]=b[y][z-1];

      b[y][z-1]=temp;

      *x=((y*10)+(z-1));

      return b[4][4];

    }

    }
  else 

    {
      if(*x!=((y*10)+(z+1)))

    {
      printf("Invalid Move");

      return b[4][4];
    }

      else
    {

      temp=b[y][z];

      b[y][z]=b[y][z+1];

      b[y][z+1]=temp;

      *x=((y*10)+(z+1));

      return b[4][4];

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: choice(a[4][4],&p,row,col,c); 
should be 
 choice(a,&p,row,col,c);

Comment: Suggestion simplify expressions like `*x!=(((y-1)*10)+z)`

Comment: Thanks a lot bro !! Can you please tell me why?

Comment: It is happening because the choice function expects an array for the first argument. However you are passing it an integer element. Further, there is a mistake in your mistake. The array size is 4 therefore a[4][4] is actually invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of weirdness here, but it might be enough to pass `a` (a pointer to a 2D array) rather than `a[4][4]` (an `int`) when you call your function. Quite apart from the fact that `a[4][4]` is outside of the bounds of the array (the last element is `a[3][3]`...) That way you can actually manipulate the contents of the array inside the `choice` function.

Another problem: your will print the "you won" message as soon as a tile matches the solution:

```
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
     if(a[i][j]==w[i][j])
       {
     printf("Game finished.. YOU WON!!!");
       }
   }
 }
```

You need to do an "AND" of all the tiles being equal:

```
 int winFlag = 1;
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
     winFlag = winFlag && (a[i][j]==w[i][j]);
   }
 }

 if(winFlag) 
 {
   ...
 }
```

Notice also that your way of using `goto` to jump around the code is considered poor code structure - usually it is better to wrap your steps inside of `while` loops.

There may be many more problems...

Comment: used a integer count so now if all tiles match then i will check if count is 16 (as its a 4x4 matrix) then it will print you won

Comment: got it.. now its running properly.. had few more changes in the function.. thanks

Comment: Using an integer count of matching tiles is a good idea. Glad you got it all working. You might consider editing your question with a new section: "here are all the changes I made and now it's working".

Answer (score 0):

Have you learned functions?

You are passing array the wrong way to the function `choice`

```
choice(a[4][4],&p,row,col,c);
```

The correct way is:

```
choice(a,&p,row,col,c);
```

Besides you can't access `a[4][4]`, this is most probably the cause of Segmentation fault.

***Next time please post the relevent code only***